# Do we have built-in hexadecimal to binary conversion in tcl?

Tags: tcl

I need help to figure out a built-in hexadecimal to binary conversion in Tcl; I am currently using TCL 8.5.

Similar to hex to dec conversion, do we have for hex to bin
*or*
any one liner syntax for doing the conversion?

Comment: You mean [this](http://wiki.tcl.tk/3242)?

Comment: @Jerry not exaclty was trying point out like  (http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/format.htm), example: say convert decimal to hexadecimal '% puts [format %x 33] 21 %' Or hexadecimal to decimal '% puts [format %d 0x21] 33 %'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by binary; do you mean a sequences of bytes or a sequence of `0` and `1` characters?

Converting from hexadecimal to a byte sequence (which is a string that happens to only have characters in the range `\u0000` to `\u00ff`) is done with the `binary format` command:

```
set hex "61626364"
set bytes [binary format H* $hex]
puts $bytes
# Prints 'abcd'
```

To convert to a sequence of digits that represent bits, you convert to a binary string as above and then use `binary scan` to convert back:

```
set hex "61626364"
# No option to get the value without writing it to a variable
binary scan [binary format H* $hex] B* bits
puts $bits
# Prints '01100001011000100110001101100100'
```

All the above work on Tcl 8.5. Note that you need to use *upper case* `H*` and `B*` or the code will try to do something which it claims is “little endian” (and might actually be so) and which confuses me a lot.

Comment: :was looking for binary sequence of 0's and 1's, your second solution will workout for me (this option i have already), thanks for the answer

Comment: What if it's a decimal we want to convert into hex? Is there a specifier like H* for decimal? Where is all this documented I couldn't find anything after a quick search.